# What are these random .partial files created in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and on-premise TFS as source control. Occasionally when doing a check in, I see randomly created .parial files included in my list of changes:

[image: Screenshot of file in question]

I didn't add those files and I usually just shrug and right-click/undo to get rid of them.

My guess is that they're a symptom of doing a 'Get Latest' before attempting a check in, and they're used by Visual Studio to check for conflicts or something. But here, I'm seeing them before they are being removed.

Can anyone provide a better explanation?

Edit - it's not quite the same as the suggested duplicate, which is talking about checking files out whereas I'm talking about checking in.

Comment: I saw that potential duplicate, but it's talking about checking files out, not in. Admittedly it may well be the same root cause though.

Comment: Did you try the solution there? (change the workspace)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to worry about .partial files, they are auto generated when a duplication of an old file exists.